# Why $ax^2+bx+c = a(x-r)(x-s)$, where $r$, $s$ are the roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, roots, quadratics

When I was reading about math, I came across the following -

> Suppose the roots of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ are $r$ and $s$.
>
> Then $ax^2+bx+c = a(x-r)(x-s)$ for all values of $x$.

Is there any way to prove the above statement? I tried substituting for a few values and it worked but I couldn't prove that it works for all values of $x$.

Comment: $a(x-r)(x-s)=ax^2-a(r+s)x+ars=ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can use vieta's to prove that.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need here two lemmas.

1. In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ there is a division with residues.
2. if $s$ is a root of p(x) then $p(x)=g(x)(x-s)$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just prove that $r = \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} $ and $s = \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$, where $\Delta = b^2-4ac$. Then your solution comes on its own.
To do this you have to put your expression in the canonic form :
$$
ax^2+bx+c = a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})
$$
$$
= a[(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{a}]
$$
and I think you can figure out the end of it, supposing that you effectively have two solutions, which implies that the second member of the substraction is positive...
Well it's a bit long but works